# jquery.dataTables.js: Cannot read properties of undefined with Svelte

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte

I use svelte 3 with datatables.js and jquery.js in browser only (not ssr).

After datatables make ajax request and try to create table I got error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'createElement')
    at _fnCreateTr (jquery.dataTables.js:3160)
```

In firefox error was:  Uncaught TypeError: document is undefined .

With chrome debuger I see that document == undefined .

How is posible that document is not defined in browser?

My code is:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import {onMount, tick} from "svelte";

    import jQuery from 'jquery'
    import dt from 'datatables.net-dt'

    import {flatten, SITE_URL} from "../config";
    import fixJquery from "../includes/jquery.spring-friendly";


    dt(jQuery)


    function handleError(xhr, error, thrown) {
        console.error("ERROR", xhr.responseText);
    }

    fixJquery(jQuery);
    onMount(async () => {
        await tick();

        jQuery(document).ready( function () {

            let dataTable = jQuery("#example").DataTable(
                {
                    processing: true,
                    serverSide: true,
                    ajax: {
                        url: SITE_URL + "/users/datatables",
                        type: "GET",
                        error: handleError
                    },
                    columns: [
                        {
                            data: 'id'
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'name'
                        }
                    ],
                }
            );
        });
    });


</script>

<div>
    <h2>User list</h2>

    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is Svelte REPL with this problem: [svelte.dev/repl/8354f4daadc04165a59dbac5be41e253?version=3.44.2](https://svelte.dev/repl/8354f4daadc04165a59dbac5be41e253?version=3.44.2)

Comment: I tried to re-create the issue based on your code but couldn't.  Without the additional libraries the `document` variable is available just as usual.
Can you make a Svelte REPL that reproduces the issue & provide the link to it?

Comment: Here is Svelte REPL with this problem: https://svelte.dev/repl/8354f4daadc04165a59dbac5be41e253?version=3.44.2

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you load DataTables library, it may see a different scope of the world and differently initialised jQuery. I encountered this issue before. Thus, it is better to explicitly initialise DataTables and pass jQuery and its document to it.

[Here is some of our open source code that is using Svelte + DataTables (+ its jQuery dependency)](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/frontend/blob/master/src/lib/datatable/datatable.svelte)

[You can see the live website here using Svelte + DataTables](https://tradingstrategy.ai/trading-view/trading-pairs).

Comment: I was fixed with this examples.  I corrected by this example. Here is the code that works. But I still don't understand how it is possible for a document to be undefined in a browser. Here is fixed version https://svelte.dev/repl/322a441d233f4cecbdfd8ca0bf5af74c?version=3.44.2

Comment: @user1206570 It's true that the global `document` variable cannot be overwritten. However, it can be easily shadowed.

Here's an example to demonstrate it: https://jsfiddle.net/yheon5jk/1/

The place where the `document` was undefined was in a callback function, so somewhere further up the call stack there was a `var document=undefined` or something to that effect. So it that context `document` was undefined.

Comment: This and the fact that jQuery package needs to work on the server-side where `window` and `document` objects are not available.